# Find contact force given sphere's radii and distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I simulate scenario of two contacting elastic spheres, where their radii and the distance of their centers is known, and repulsive force should be computed. Material parameters are also given. Most contact mechanics references (also the Wikipedia page on [Contact mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_mechanics) give equations for determining $a$ (contact area radius) when the force $F$ is already known.

Simpler contact models such as Hertz are able to express force as function of overlap of undeformed spheres ($F=\frac{4}{3}E^*\sqrt{R^*}\delta^{\frac{3}{2}}$), but the more complicated ones always only give an equation for $a$ supposing $F$ is already known; it does not seem that $F$ can be analytically expressed from those equations - e.g. in the Carpick-Ogletree-Salmeron model with $a=a_0(\beta) \left(\cfrac{\beta + \sqrt{1 - F/F_c(\beta)}}{1 + \beta}\right)^{2/3}$.

So, in the case of more complicated models such as the COS one:

1. do I need to find $F$ iteratively so that the equation for $a$ is satisfied, or am I overlooking something obvious?
2. What is the relationship between $a$ and the overlap $\delta$?

I will be also grateful for any good reference.